# adding a grouped-by zscore column to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I can insert a column into a dataframe that z-scores another column like this:

```
[1] df.insert(<loc>, column='ZofA', value=(df['A']-df['A'].mean())/df['A'].std())
```

I can do a simple reduction of a column grouped by 2 other columns like this:

```
[2] df.groupby(['C1', 'C2'])['A'].mean()
```

I tried to replace the simple mean() function in [2] with the zscore function in [1], but couldn't figure out how to do it, including with .apply -- e.g. this fails:

```
[3] df.groupby(['C1', 'C2']).apply((df['A']-df['A'].mean())/df['A'].std())
```

So my first problem is I apparently don't know how to create a zscore column with grouping.

My second problem is that I want to combine (1) inserting a new column into a dataframe ('ZofA') that holds z-scores from another column ('A'), with (2) having those zscores be calculated within groups defined by two other columns('C1', 'C2'). And (3) I'd like to do all this inside one df.insert() statement. Am I just messing up my parentheses and brackets and what-not, or am I trying to do too much in one statement?  Thanks!

Comment: Do It by the book: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html you have the exact example in the doc

Comment: Please post it as an answer and mark it as correct if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks for the pointer to the documentation. For any who are curious, I thought I'd post the solution. First, put the zscore calculation into a lambda:

```
zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
```

The magic ingredient is .transform. Just write the insert statement like this:

```
df.insert(<loc>, 'ZofA', df.groupby(['C1', 'C2'])['A'].transform(zscore))
```

The solution is indeed in the "Group By: split-apply-combine" document. You just have to scroll down about halfway to the "Transformation" section. I ignored the stuff about the date key and just plugged my grouping columns directly into the groupby statement.

Comment: I am still learning `pandas`, but that `<loc>` doesn't look like valid python. What is it doing?

Comment: You're right. Just replace <loc> with the integer representing where you want the new column to go in the dataframe. '1' would put it before the current first column, '2' would put it after the first but before the second column, etc. Wherever the new column is inserted, all the columns to its right get shifted one one position to the right.